# PrimeFaces poll does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to use `<p:poll />` in some other work. So I was trying out the PrimeFaces ShowCase code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
    <h:form>
    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterView.number}" />
    <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{counterView.increment()}" update="txt_count" />
    </h:form>
</html>
```

And the backing bean is as below:-

```
package com.poll;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean (name="counterView")
@ViewScoped
public class CounterView implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void increment() {
        number++;
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

It works as such: in browser `number` shows as 0 and doesn't change. In console I can see it printing as 1 once and then nothing.

What is wrong here? I am using PrimeFaces 3.4.2 on JSF 2.1

Comment: Should work, Only thing I would try is removing of `()` in the `listener` attribute, like `#{counterView.increment}` instead of `#{counterView.increment()}`

Comment: `<p:poll process="@this" .../>`

Comment: Next time please please please read the docs of the right PF version to see what is supported

Comment: Which [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase) page exactly did you got that code from? The XML namespace is for PrimeFaces 2.x which already don't exist for years. I can't imagine it still being shown in their showcase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `p:poll` tag does work for me with the following content, and I am on `Primefaces 5.2`.

**NOTE:** `<h:head/>` tag is needed and without that it does load primefaces related js files that are needed. I believe that is the reason why the refresh is not working in your case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head/>

<h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterView.number}" />
            <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{counterView.increment}" update="txt_count" />
        </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

And the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="counterView")
@ViewScoped
public class CounterView implements Serializable {

    private int number = 100;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void increment() {
        System.out.println("Incrementing....");
        number++;
    }
}
```

Can you try with these and compare if it works.

**UPDATE: Final Solution**

To summarize the solution, along the `<h:head/>` tag, upgrading to newer version (5.x) of Primefaces helped resolve the issue, as indicated in the comments section.

Comment: But then it says Property increment not found on type counterView (the bean)

Comment: It makes no difference, the listener method is called once, I can see it prints the once incremented value (1) but then it doesn't print and the text doesn't change. Precisely, it is polling only once and stopping

Comment: @SohamBanerjee Do you have `<h:head/>` tag? Not sure, but can copy/paste the above code and try, just to rule out any possibility of mistake. By the way, which `version of primefaces` are you on?

Comment: I copied your code entirely, still it is executing only once, as before. Only change that I made is instead of `listener="#{counterView.increment}"` I had to use `listener="#{counterView.increment()}"` , otherwise I get error as I said before

Comment: @SohamBanerjee hmm..Wondering why is it not working with `listener="#{counterView.increment}"`. It looks you are on 3.4.2 ver of Primefaces which is quite old. Any reason not to move to 5.x. I tried with 5.2 though.

Comment: Let me try upgrading

Comment: Just one question, To use <p:poll> should the bean necessarily be serializable?

Comment: @SohamBanerjee For poll to work it doesn't need to be Serializable. Able to see the refreshed value on the browser even without Serializable.